# link to view changes axis range pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqtgraph

Assume that I have two views\plots created in pyqtgraph and then they are linked.
using lines

```
p2.setYLink('Plot1')
p2.setXLink('Plot1')
```

Question is that when we link the views, the ranges of both the views are made equal, which raises issue as one plot appears to be too much zoomed out or zoomed in.
We just want to link the views to zoom together but don't want the ranges to change as the plot looks changed.

Below is sample code that explains the issue visually

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

#QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('raster')
try:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
except RuntimeError:
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = x1

x2 = [10,20,30,40,50]
y2 = x2

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="pyqtgraph example: Linked Views")
win.resize(800,600)

win.addLabel("Linked Views", colspan=2)
win.nextRow()

p1 = win.addPlot(x=x1, y=y1, name="Plot1", title="Plot1")
p2 = win.addPlot(x=x2, y=y2, name="Plot2", title="Plot2: Y linked with Plot1")
p2_state = p2.vb.getState()
p1_state = p1.vb.getState()

p2.setLabel('bottom', "Label to test offset")
p2.setYLink('Plot1')  ## test linking by name
p2.setXLink('Plot1')

app.exec_()
```

Comment: You have not fully specified the behavior you want: 1) Do you want both views to always show the same scale (so `xmax1-xmin1 == xmax2-xmin2`), or do you just want scale *changes* in one view to be mirrored in the other?  2) If I zoom one view, then around what point should the other view be zoomed to match? Usually zoom is around the mouse click point, but for the other view, this would not make sense.

Comment: So the fucntionality that I had in my mind was:
1. Both the views should not show the same scale. It should be like they should be having the view fitted to show the plot. In the example that I had given, if one plot is in view then other one goes out. 
So I think it is that state changed in one should be mirrored in another.
2. Well I think my pain point was w.r.t. the first scenario. This second scenario if it bothers you w.r.t. implementation then please let me know further details so that I can provide my further input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restate the question: you want to have two views that can have different ranges and scales, but when you zoom with the mouse in one view, the other view will zoom by the same amount.

This is *not* the intended function of the setXLink/setYLink methods, so you will need to implement this by subclassing or monkey-patching the viewboxes. For example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

p1 = pg.plot([1,6,2,4,3])
p2 = pg.plot([30,50,10,70,20])

def scaleBy(*args, **kwds):
    pg.ViewBox.scaleBy(p1.plotItem.vb, *args, **kwds)
    pg.ViewBox.scaleBy(p2.plotItem.vb, *args, **kwds)

p1.plotItem.vb.scaleBy = scaleBy
p2.plotItem.vb.scaleBy = scaleBy
```

There is a problem, however, that you need know two things when scaling: *how much* to scale by (this is the same for both views, so not a problem), and *around what point* to scale (this is different between the views, so a bit more difficult to determine). The solution to this depends on your desired behavior.

Comment: This was a start to resolve the issue. Thanks for the pointer